# Feature extraction from trained images via CNN into dataset

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, feature-extraction, conv-neural-network

My goal is to utilize `ConvNN` to extract the important features given a folder of images of the two types, say dog and cat. From the implementation of the MNIST found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py), I want to know if where and how I can extract the features from the trained images **into a dataset** so that I can use it as an input dataset for another classifier. I have spent a long time trying to do that by myself but I couldn't do so. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: mind posting your codes?

Answer (score 0):

To get the features, just pass the layer called `dense` to your `sess.run()` statement. Then you add the output to a list and do it again with the next image.